# PHP Undefined offset: -1 in comparison loop

Tags: php

I am receiving this error **Undefined offset: -1.**

I am pretty sure it is because I am comparing a value of an array index with the value of the previous index, so on the first iteration its failing because there is no -1 index.

```
for ($i=0; $i<$rows_n; $i++) 
{
    formatTR($i, $rows, 'YEAR');
}


// Function
function formatTR($i, $rows, $year) 
{

    if ($rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {
        print "<tr class='header-year-tr'><td colspan='2'>{$rows[$year][$i]}</td></tr>";
    }

    print "<tr>";
}
```

The function checks to see if the previous value of $rows[year][i] is the same as the previous $rows[year][i-1]. If its different, it prints out a formatted < TR >.

Seems like a way to avoid this error would be to first check if the value of $i is zero, but I'm wondering if there is another way. Possibly in my if conditional.

Comment: You should start with `$i = 1`.

Comment: `if ($rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {` should be `if (!isset($rows[$year][$i-1]) || $rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1]) {`

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks the isset check worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easest way is to check if $i>0

```
if ($i > 0 && $rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined offset" is almost always an off-by-one error, and here is the culprit:

```
if ($rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {
-------------------------------------^^^^
```

Make sure you never call this row if `$i == 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
function formatTR($i, $rows, $year) 
{
    if($i > 0){
        if ($rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {
        print "<tr class='header-year-tr'><td colspan='2'>{$rows[$year][$i]}</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    print "<tr>"; //not sure why you have this here.

}
```

If you want `$rows[$year][0]` to print a `<tr>`:

```
function formatTR($i, $rows, $year) 
{
    if($i > 0){
        if ($rows[$year][$i] != $rows[$year][$i-1] ) {
          print "<tr class='header-year-tr'><td colspan='2'>{$rows[$year][$i]}</td></tr>";
        }
    } else {
        print "<tr class='header-year-tr'><td colspan='2'>{$rows[$year][$i]}</td></tr>";
    }
    print "<tr>"; //not sure why you have this here.

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an isset check that DaveRandom Suggested, but this would have also worked well.